# Surface integral $\iint_Y \textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{N} dS$ using Gauss theorem (divergence theorem)

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

Calculate the surface integer
$$\iint_Y \textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{N} dS$$
Where Y: $(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2=1-z^2$ and $0 \leq z \leq 1$ (**N** is outward oriented). $\textbf{F} = (y,x,1+x^2z)$

If i shortly summarize what i have done:

I started with adding horizontal planes at $z = 0$ (call this plane B) and $z = 1$ (L), now the entire volume is restricted and we can use Gauss theorem.

$$\iint_Y \textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{N} dS + 
\iint_B \textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{N} dS +
\iint_L \textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{N} dS = \iiint \text{div}\textbf{F}dxdydz$$

However, since we are orientating outwards we get that $\textbf{N}_L = (0,0,1)$ and $\textbf{N}_B = (0,0,-1)$, therefore we have that

$$\iint_Y \textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{N} dS  = \iiint \text{div}\textbf{F}dxdydz$$
(Is this correct?)

From here i simply get div **F**$= (0,0,x^2)$ and then i calculate the tripple integer useing the following limits
$$0 \leq z \leq 1 \Rightarrow 1 \leq x,y \leq 2$$
Giving me the final answer 6.

I dont have the key but I'm almost 100% sure I made atleast one mistake somewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, just a quick tip that you can type multiple integrals using \iint and \iiint

$$ \iint \qquad \qquad \iiint$$

instead of doing \int\int or \int\int\int.

---

You have the right idea of trying to add in planes to make your domain closed in order to use the Divergence Theorem. However, note that at $z=1$ we have

$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 = 0$$

which is just a single point $(x,y)=(1,1)$, so we don't actually need the $z=1$ plane. Indeed, we then have

$$\iint_Y \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf N \, dS + \iint_B \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf N \, dS = \iiint_R \nabla \cdot \mathbf F \, dV$$

However, $B$ is **NOT** the entire $z=0$ plane. It is only the portion of it that is inside $Y$. i.e.

$$B = \{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 : x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \; , \; z = 0\}$$

$R$ is then the region bounded by $Y$ and $B$, i.e.

$$R = \{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 : (x-z)^2+(y-z)^2 \leq 1-z^2 \; , \; 0 \leq z \leq 1 \}$$

I believe you know how to do the rest from this point onwards, but I shall leave you with the full solution anyways.

As you said, the outward unit normal at $B$ is $(0,0,-1)$, so

$$\iint_B \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf N \, dS = \iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq 1} \begin{pmatrix} y \\ x \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} \, dS = \iint_{x^2+y^2 \leq 1}(-1) \, dS = -\pi$$

As for the other integral, we need to parameterise $R$, which can be done using

$$x = z+r\cos \theta \quad y = z + r\sin \theta \quad z = z$$

where $0\leq r \leq \sqrt{1-z^2}$, $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, $0 \leq z \leq 1$. The Jacobian is

$$J = \det \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial z} \end{pmatrix} = \det \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -r\sin \theta & 1 \\ \sin\theta & r\cos \theta & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = r$$

Moreover, we compute

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf F = x^2$$

(note that taking the divergence of a vector gives you a scalar!). It follows that

$$\iiint_R \nabla \cdot \mathbf F \, dV = \int_{z=0}^{z=1}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{r=\sqrt{1-z^2}}\big(z+r\cos\theta)^2 \cdot rdrd\theta dz = \frac{4\pi}{15}$$